# Select distinct column values from multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have 100 databases from customers who all have the same schema but different content.

Now I wanted to some analysis and start out with running a distinct of one column over all databases. My instance contains these and more.

I think it is close to

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'Use ? select distinct [ColumName] from [TableName]'
```

However, that does not combine them; surrounding this with a `select` also does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were some issues with an [earlier version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/292513/2) of another answer, so I'm going to put this here, as a slightly different version of the same thing:

- String aggregation via variable should be avoided, you should use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead
- You must use `QUOTENAME` to quote database names, in case there are characters that need quoting.

  For example, consider what happens if there is a database called `My]Database`, or `My]..SomeTable;DROP DATABASE OtherDatabase; --`.

Solution:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(N'
SELECT [ColumnName] 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(D.[name]) + '.SchemaName.TableName
'
        AS nvarchar(max)), N'
UNION
')
    FROM sys.databases
);

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the [`UNION` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), though I don't think you can use this with the `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure. The `UNION` operator automatically removes duplicates for you.

Easiest solution might be to pre-create a `#TempTable` and leverage that in your call to `sp_MSforeachdb` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTableName (ColumName DataType);
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'Use ? INSERT INTO #TempTableName SELECT [ColumName] FROM [TableName]';

SELECT DISTINCT ColumName
FROM #TempTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempTableName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempTableName
    END 
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTableName (C1 nvarchar(2))

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb  'IF ''?''  NOT IN (''tempDB'',''model'',''msdb'',''master'')
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #TempTableName SELECT DISTINCT [SOMEFIELD] FROM [?].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
END 
'

SELECT DISTINCT C1, count(c1) FROM #TempTableName 
group by c1
order by count(c1)
```